# Using LINQ to transform Date into a WeekDay and Week of Month

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to transform this MySQL select query date functions into LINQ. But I do not know the LINQ version for WEEKDAY or DayOfMOnth. Working SQL below. I found DayOfWeek but cannot understand what it does or how to use it for what I am trying to achieve. Any help is appreciated, thanks

```
Day = WEEKDAY(JS.Date),
Week = FLOOR((DayOfMonth(JS.Date)-1)/7)+1
```

Full Code here

```
var rows = from JS in _context.JobSales 

        join Msg in _context.Commenting.Where(a => a.ReplyTo == 0  && a.ToolSection == 2) on
            JS.Job equals Msg.ToolId
            into cmt from Msg in cmt.DefaultIfEmpty()

        orderby JS.Date descending, JS.Job
        where shopId_Array.Contains((char)JS.ShopId)
        && id == JS.ShopId
        && year == JS.Year
        && month == JS.Month
        select new {
            total = JS.RemoveRefit + JS.Repair + JS.Paint + JS.Parts + JS.SubMisc + JS.Other + JS.Mechanical + JS.Electrical,
            Day = WEEKDAY(JS.Date),
            Week = FLOOR((DayOfMonth(JS.Date)-1)/7)+1
        };

        //Return Results
        return rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SqlFunctions.DatePart?

Code would look something like this, I haven't tested it.

```
var weekday = _myTableRepository
.Select(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday",x.CreationDate));
```

Comment: No. Can it handle both things?

Comment: I have used DatePart before and it works, but I'm not sure about floor. Will let you know when I find something

Comment: cheers Sakkie thanks for your help. It's used to push the # weeks of the month according to mon-fri's

Comment: my pleasure Micheal

Comment: Hey Sakkie, is there a special technique to bring in SQLFunctions to your C# file?

Comment: Remember to include the namespace using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

Comment: This worked for me             using (var db = new entity.Entities())
            {
                var data = (from t in db.Tables
                            where t.Id == 1
                            select SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", t.DateField)).FirstOrDefault();
            }

Comment: use the same parameter values as you would use using it in SQL,  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datepart.asp